# Khinchin's Entropy Axioms

Tags: information-theory

Khinchin (1957) famously proved the uniqueness theorem for Shannon's entropy under 4 axioms.
Let $\mathbf{p}=(p_{1},\cdots,p_{n})$ be a probability distribution. Let $X$ be an random element following $\mathbf{p}$. (I will use the notation $H(X)$ and $H(\mathbf{p})$ interchangeablly below.) The 4 axioms are

1. $H(\mathbf{p})$ is continuous with respect to all its arguments.
2. $H(\mathbf{p})$ is maximized at $\mathbf{p}$ being uniform ($p_{i}=1/n$ for all $i$).
3. $H(p_{1},\cdots,p_{n},0)=H(p_{1},\cdots,p_{n})$.
4. $H(X,Y)=H(Y)+\sum_{i=1}^{I} P(X=i)H(Y|X=i)$
   where $P(X=i)$ is the marginal probability of $X$ takes the $i$th letter and $H(Y|X=i)$ is the entropy of the conditional distribution of $Y$ given $X$ takes the $i$th letter.

However I have seen, in some writings,  the four axioms are re-stated with the first one being replaced by

- (1*.)
  $H(\mathbf{p})$ is symmetric with respect to all its arguments (label independence).

I wonder if replacing 1. by 1*. is a mistake or creates an equivalent axiomatic set.

Comment: Fix your notation, you should have $H(Y|X=i)$ in item 4. The expression $H(X|Y)$ you have is the average conditional entropy. Also $p_{i,.}$ is nonstandard just use $P(X=i).$

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you add links to sources with the 1* axiom? I flipped through Khinchin's book and that certainly uses 1, as do more recent papers with axiomatic characterisations of other entropies.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 See page 2 of the file at:https://www.stat.cmu.edu/~cshalizi/350/2008/lectures/06a/lecture-06a.pdf